# How to start Chrome without images using Watir?

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I have tried this method but its not working .

```
 prefs = {
        :profile => {
            :managed_default_content_settings => { 
              :images => 2
            }
        }
    }

    Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
    browser.goto "http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: Try `webkit: { webprefs: { loads_images_automatically: false } }` or `profile: { default_content_setting_values: { images: 2 } }`

Comment: you need with Watir? or with anyway?

Comment: I need it with Watir because my automation code is in watir

Comment: @Stefan I have tried both methods still showing the images ..

Comment: can use Selenium for start without image and after this use watir

Comment: @TalaatMagdy i have tried this but my it show the following error that Selenium Wbdriver does not support the comands of watir.

Comment: @TalaatMagdy this is the following for `selenium options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new 
  options.add_preference('webkit.webprefs.loads_images_automatically', false)`

Comment: @TalaatMagdy Still does not work with watir as i said before i know how to open browser without images using Selenium but i want it to know how i can Open using Watir because all my code is in Ruby Watir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205859/discussion-between-procode-development-and-talaat-magdy).

Comment: @ProcodeDevelopment work or not . I see some of answer is good

Comment: @TalaatMagdy no its not correct but anyway thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

`:prefs` needs to be a key within the `:options` Hash:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}
```

Specifically for disabling images:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :chrome,
  options: {
    prefs: {'webkit.webprefs.loads_images_automatically' => false}
  }
)
browser.goto('www.google.com')
p browser.image.loaded?
#=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is like this

```
 profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
        profile['webkit.webprefs.loads_images_automatically'] = false

        @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

Answer (score -2):

**First, create a browser object like this:**

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

**This will open an empty Chrome window (assuming you have it installed) that you can control now.**

```
browser.goto("google.com")
```

Chrome will navigate to this URL, and the page will load as if you typed the URL yourself.

**Now:**
You can do anything you would normally do on a website with your mouse & keyboard.

**Example:**

```
browser.link(text: "All Posts").click
```

Comment: The topic is for something else not for opening the browser and click links